# Not sure what space complexity my map object uses in the example?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm learning to analyze space complexity, but I'm confused of analyzing an array vs an object in JS.  So I'd like to get some help here.

ex1. array []

```
int[] table = new int[26];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    table[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
}
```

ex1. is from an example online, and it says the space complexity is O(1) because the table's size stays constant.

ex2. object {}

```
let nums[0,1,2,3,4,5], map = {};
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
   map[ nums[i] ] = i;
}
```

I think ex2. uses O(n) because the map object is accessed 6 times.  However, if I use the concept learned from ex1., the space complexity should be O(1)?  Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: "complexity" is not a value, it's a function. If `N` is the amount of data we deal with, "complexity" tells us how the space/time usage will grow as `N` increases. If it doesn't change at all, the complexity is said to be constant, if it grows at the same rate as N, it's linear, etc. Since there's no changing N in your examples, it makes no sense to talk about their complexity.

Comment: @georg , could you clarify your comment? ... b/c The N in table[] in ex1. doesn't change, but the N in map{} in ex2 does change as map{} gets resized when new items addded to it.

Comment: Your examples don't accept inputs, there is no changing data. Therefore we can't say anything about their complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the complexity analysis point of view, **in ex 1, the complexity is O(1)** because the array size doesn't increase. Because you are initializing the table to a fixed size of 26 (Looks like you are counting the characters in a string?).

See the below example that keeps track of counts of a alphabets in a string (Only small letters for clarity). In this case the length of array which tracks the count of alphabets never change even if the string changes its length.

```
function getCharacterCount(s){
    const array = new Int8Array(26);
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        array[s.charCodeAt(i) - 97]++;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Now let's change the implementation to map instead. Here the size of the map increases as and when a new character is encountered in the string.So

**Theoretically speaking, the space complexity is O(n)**.

But in reality, we started with map with length 0 (0 keys) and  it doesn't go beyond 26. If the string doesn't contain all the characters, the space taken would be much lesser than an array as in previous implementation.

```
function getCharacterCountMap(s){
    const map = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        const charCode = s.charCodeAt(i) - 97;
        if(map[charCode]){
            map[charCode] = map[charCode] + 1
        }else{
            map[charCode] = 0;
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

```js
function getCharacterCount(s){
    const array = new Int8Array(26);
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        array[s.charCodeAt(i) - 97]++;
    }
    return array;
}

function getCharacterCountMap(s){
    const map = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        const charCode = s.charCodeAt(i) - 97;
        if(map[charCode]){
            map[charCode] = map[charCode] + 1
        }else{
            map[charCode] = 1;
        }
    }
    return map;
}

console.log(getCharacterCount("abcdefabcedef"));
console.log(getCharacterCountMap("abcdefabcdef"));
```